# How to replace string to another string which can back to original using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, security, encryption

I want to replace string to another string which can back to original using c#
For example If I entered

> "XcXa$2A"

then clicked on button, output will be the following string:

> "t6tYQA*"

That's because for my example

```
X replaced by t 
c replaced by 6
a replaced by Y
A replaced by *
$ replaced by Q
2 replaced by A
```

And also the output string can be back to the original string from another button "t6tYQA*" can be back to original "XcXa$2A" 
So I need all characters in keyboard to be replaced to another and output can be back to original.
Thanks in advance.
I need that for secure all my string and don't need to use encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: "I need that for secure all my string " - please don't labour for too long under the misapprehension that this is in any way secure

Comment: Just use a `SecureString` - don't reinvent the wheel. Or use your x-man cryptography skills on is mere mortals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Create a `Dictionary<string, string> dict` object and store all your mappings here.
2. Create a method to get mapping:

   ```
   string GetEncryptedData(string s)
   {
      StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
      foreach(char c in s.ToCharArray()
      {
         s.Append(dict[c]);
      }
      return s.ToString();
    }
   ```
3. Create a method to get reverse mapping:

   ```
   string GetDecryptedData(string s)
   {
      StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
      foreach(char c in s.ToCharArray()
      {
          s.Append(dict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == c).Key;);
      }
      return s.ToString();
    }
   ```

Comment: Dictionary is readable but perhaps a bit heavyweight; this could actually be done with a char array, because char can be cast to an int, for the array index , e.g. `map['X'] = 't'; (

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is there way to fill the Dictionary automatically not manual because I don't know all characters.

Comment: Suppose you have all mappings in mapping.csv, then use, `var dict = File.ReadLines("mapping.csv").Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToDictionary(line => line[0], line => line[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet will give you the encrypted and decrypted equivalent as per your need. And also you can easily decrypt it.

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {            
                string input = "sudar";

                string encodedInput = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
                string decodedInput = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedInput));

                Console.WriteLine("Actual text:" + input);
                Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Value: " + encodedInput);
                Console.WriteLine("Decrypted Value: " + decodedInput);

                List<string> encryptedList = new List<string>();

                Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Data:");

                foreach (char c in input.ToCharArray())
                {
                    string encryptedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c.ToString()));
                    Console.WriteLine(c + " replaced by " + encryptedValue);
                    encryptedList.Add(encryptedValue);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Decrypted Data:");
                foreach (string s in encryptedList)
                {
                    string decryptedValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(s));
                    Console.WriteLine(s + " replaced by " + decryptedValue);
                }

                Console.Read();

            }
        }
```

[image: Output of the below code]